# AWS CLI: Can I set a user's inline policy from source other than local file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

The [AWS CLI put-user-policy documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/put-user-policy.html) doesn't describe the `--policy-document` argument other than being a JSON-format string. The example uses a local file, e.g. `--policy-document file://AdminPolicy.json`

Is there a way to use the policy document from an existing, public policy?

E.g. if I wanted to use `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess` as the basis for my admin user's inline policy, can I reference it directly in the `put-user-policy` cmdline?
Or must I save the policy-document portion of the policy to a local file, then use that local file as the `--policy-document` argument using the `file:///` syntax?

---

I know you can *attach* a user-policy using `--policy-arn`; this question is specifically about inline policies, and not managed policies.

Comment: What do you mean by "as the basis for my admin user's inline policy"?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - I guess what I'm trying to ask/understand is: a newly-created user can have an inline policy and/or a managed/attached policy. You can specify a managed policy with a policy-arn using `attach-user-policy --policy-arn`. But AFAIK, the only way to specify an _inline_ policy is using `put-user-policy` which only accepts local policy document files. Is that the case, or can you directly use a policy arn with `put-user-policy`?

Comment: An inline policy is, by definition, something that is unusual and one-off. So, I don't see why you'd want to attach a 'standard' policy as an 'inline' policy. Anyway, I think your findings are correct.